# Paypal's Instant Payment Notification

Tags: paypal

I'm trying out PayPal's Instant Payment Notification, and it is sending me two (2) transactions instead of one.

Any reason why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you log all the variables that it sends you, you will find that they are of different status. For example, the first may be "Pending".